# Как обновлять файл с Python на GitHub?

Tags: python, python-3.x, github

Задача: нужно на гитхаб через `python` динамически обновлять файл с ip адресами.

То есть, мне интересно, могу ли я хранить список "серверов" на github и динамически его добавлять, чтобы из своего клиента я мог выбрать к какому из них подключиться?

Comment: Да, можете, почему нет

Comment: Как обновлять - коммит и пуш.

Comment: @insolor, ну мало ли есть специальная либа) Да и мне надо на гитхаб только отправлять одну строчку, а не качать весь файл, затем его дополнять и отправлять туда. Нельзя ли как-то одну строчку только отправить?)

Comment: Зачем качать что-то? У вас же есть локальный репозиторий? Внесли изменения - коммит - пуш. Никакие файлы никуда не отправляются, уходит только `diff` - информация.

Comment: @DGDays Библиотеки есть, например [`PyGithub`](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub). Полностью файл каждый раз загружаться не будет — коммит содержит только изменения.

Comment: Возможно вам еще пригодятся гитхаб экшены. https://github.com/features/actions Сможете автоматизировать обновление.